# C# MongoDb api - Geojson geometry store into a class

Tags: c#, mongodb, geometry, geojson, mongodb-.net-driver

That's my first time that i'm approaching mongodb api. 
This is my code written up to now. I'm stuck because I can not save the polygon type coordinates inside my class and I can not run the GeoWithin function.

```
        //Connection
        MongoClient client = new MongoClient(path);
        var db = client.GetDatabase("ProgettoADM");



        //Getting the collections
        var restaurants = db.GetCollection<Restaurants>("restaurants");
        var neighborhood = db.GetCollection<Neighborhood>("neighborhood");


        // Creating variables for the query
        var longitude = -73.93414657;
        var latitude = 40.82302903;
        var point = new GeoJson2DGeographicCoordinates(longitude, latitude);
        var pnt = new GeoJsonPoint<GeoJson2DGeographicCoordinates>(point);
        var distance = 1609.34 * 5;


        //Index creation
        var restaurantsIndex = Builders<Restaurants>.IndexKeys.Geo2DSphere("location.coordinates");
        var neighborhoodIndex = Builders<Neighborhood>.IndexKeys.Geo2DSphere("geometry");
        restaurants.Indexes.CreateOne(restaurantsIndex);
        neighborhood.Indexes.CreateOne(neighborhoodIndex);

        //Filter creation for the NearSphere function            
        var nearSphereQuery = Builders<Restaurants>.Filter.NearSphere(p => p.location.coordinates, pnt, distance);

        //NearSphere Query execution
        List<Restaurants> nearSphereQueryResult = restaurants.Find(nearSphereQuery).ToListAsync().Result;

        //GeoIntersect Query execution
        var geoIntersectQuery = Builders<Neighborhood>.Filter.GeoIntersects("geometry", pnt);
        var c = neighborhood.Find(geoIntersectQuery).First();

        //Filter creation for the GeoWithin function
        var GeoWithinQuery = Builders<Restaurants>.Filter.GeoWithin(p => p.location.coordinates,/*data from variable c*/);
```

These are my classes to save data, the restaurants class works correctly, that neighborhood does not work.

```
       [BsonIgnoreExtraElements]
       public class Restaurants 
       {
          public ObjectId Id { get; set; }        
          public string name { get; set; }
          public Location location { get; set; }
       }
       [BsonIgnoreExtraElements]
       public class Location
       {               
          public double[] coordinates { get; set; }
          public string type { get; set; }
       }

       [BsonIgnoreExtraElements]
       public class Neighborhood
       {
         public ObjectId Id { get; set; }
         public string name { get; set; }
         public Geometry geometry { get; set; }
       }

       [BsonIgnoreExtraElements]
       public class Geometry
       {
         public BsonArray[] coordinates { get; set; }
       }
```

Thanks for your help!

Comment: Please clarify by what you mean when you say "does not work"

Comment: I can not save the data so I can use it as a parameter in the GeoWithin function

Comment: I'm sorry, I forgot to insert the geojson file : https://raw.githubusercontent.com/mongodb/docs-assets/geospatial/neighborhoods.json

Answer (score 0):

Here you have my helper methods

```
public static GeoJson2DGeographicCoordinates GetCoordinates(double longitude, double latitude)
{
    return new GeoJson2DGeographicCoordinates(longitude, latitude);
}

public static GeoJsonPoint<GeoJson2DGeographicCoordinates> GetJsonPoint(double x, double y)
{
    GeoJson2DGeographicCoordinates output = GetCoordinates(x, y);
    if (output == null)
    {
        return null;
    }

    return new GeoJsonPoint<GeoJson2DGeographicCoordinates>(output);
}
```

you can store them in DB as following property:

```
 public GeoJsonPoint<GeoJson2DGeographicCoordinates> Location { get; set; }
```